# Exporting a recordset from Access 2007 to spreadsheet

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

```
Private Sub Command27_Click()
Dim ltr As DAO.Recordset
Set ltr = Me.RecordsetClone
    If Not (ltr.BOF And ltr.EOF) Then
        ltr.MoveFirst
        End If
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel3, ltr, "C:\Test\db"
    Set ltr = Nothing
End Sub
```

I am trying to export specific records pulled from a table by my form to an Excel spreadsheet. I am currently getting "Run-time error '2498': An expression you entered is the wrong data type for one of these arguments."

I notice I only get this when trying to export the recordset. If I try to export the entire table I get a different error message. "Run-time error '3170': Could not find installable ISAM."

I have done some reading on this but most say they solved it by updating Office to a newer version however I already have a newer version than the posts.

Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because ltr is a RecordSet and the function expects a string.

Secondly acSpreadsheetTypeExcel3 is very old type of excel file.  I personally you should use at least acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9.  This will take care of your second error.

I believe this should work

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, ltr.Name, "C:\Test\db"
```

This is assuming ltr contains table names.  If ltr.Name returns a query then this probably won't work.